# I need to add aria-label to all links on the website using the link text as aria label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add aria-label to all links that don't have it on the site. I want to use the link text as aria-label.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").each(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('aria-label');
    if (typeof attr == typeof undefined && attr == false) {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      $(this).attr("aria-label", txt);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `typeof undefined` is? `&&` is `AND`. so how if `attr` is `false` it could be `undefined`???

Comment: Sorry i meant OR not AND. But it is not what i needed anyway:(

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this would be to use the `:not` selector to find the elements without the attribute. Then you can provide a function to `attr()` which adds it to those found. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('a:not([aria-label])').attr('aria-label', function() {
    return this.textContent.trim();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#foo">Foo Bar</a>
<a href="#fizz" aria-label="I already have a label, leave me alone">Fizz Buzz</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys! All i needed is the right conditional:) It works perfect!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 2):

Use This:

```
$("a").each(function () {
   var attr = $(this).attr('aria-label');
   if (!attr) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr("aria-label", txt);
   }
});
```

Comment: I used your version!  Thank you so so much!

Comment: Happy Coding :)